# Spring boot blank page response on browser

Tags: java, linux, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a web application using maven & spring boot with a war deployment.
While it works normally on a windows machine (starting it using netbeans), I get a blank page response from browser when I run it on a linux machine (not sure if this is relevant). No errors occur on startup.

After searching a while I found that it is related with some 404 error response of spring boot. This happens for any route that I try (valid or not)

Another clue is that I tried to redirect 404 errors to a test.jsp but nothing changed in the browsers (I still get this blank page). With postman I get this .jsp as a response.

In any case it's not normal to get an error response since the routes are correct.

Here is my **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=`"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">`
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>org</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-RELEASE</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>webapp</name>
    <description></description>


    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--         Provided 
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--<failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>-->
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                           <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib</directory>
                           <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any ideas?

---

### **EDIT**

I add some extra info that might help:

No MVC-relevant configuration is included in **application.properties**

**Application.java** (I'm not using @EnableWebMvc):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
  public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
 }
```

**Web MVC Configuration** is done by:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getPageViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you starting it; are you using maven run?

Comment: I've tried `mvn spring-boot:run`, `java -classpath "lib/*:classes/." org.app.Application` and `java -jar webapp-1.0.RELEASE.war`. Startup seemed ok on all cases.

Comment: are you sure spring starts properly, put some logging in getPageViewResolver and check if thats loaded.

Comment: @surya the log shows up normally. The problem seems to exist also in my windows machine when I start my app from terminal. It works only when I run it from netbeans

Answer (score 0):

After some tries I conclude that:

- `mvn spring-boot:run`
- `java -classpath "lib/*:classes/." org.app.Application`
- `java -jar webapp-1.0.RELEASE.war`

start the app as a normal application which leads to this problem. No matter if pom packing is defined as jar or war (If I'm wrong someone pls correct me)

Netbeans was deploying the app into an external tomcat server. I finally tried the classic war deployment way in order to make it work.

This answer is not solving the original question but provides a fix in case someone else has the same problem.